# batch script that removes special characters and replaces them with spaces for lines starting with 'AB' in multiple files only

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that removes special characters and replaces them with spaces for lines starting with 'IN' in multiple files only for the lines that starts with 'IN'. However, I am not getting anything changed. The file remains the same.

Please help with the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "targetFolder=D:\ach_test"
echo Processing: !targetFolder!

pause

for %%F in ("%targetFolder%\*.txt") do (
    set "filePath=%%F"
    set "fileName=%%~nxF"
    echo Processing: !filePath!
    echo Processing: !fileName!

    rem Create a temporary file
    set "tempFile=!fileName!.tmp"

    rem Process each line in the file
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("!filePath!") do (
        set "line=%%L"

        rem Check if the line starts with 'IN'
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if "!line:~0,2!"=="IN" (

            rem Extract the first 15 characters
            set "prefix=!line:~0,15!"

            rem Remove special characters from the prefix and replace them with spaces
            for /F "delims=" %%A in ('echo !prefix! ^| findstr /R /N /C:"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"') do (
                set "line=%%A"
                setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
                for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%N in ("!line!") do (
                    endlocal
                    set "prefix=!prefix:~0,%%N!"
                )
            )
            set "line=!prefix!!line:~15!"
        )
        endlocal

        rem Append the modified line to the temporary file
        echo !line! >> "!tempFile!"
    )

    rem Replace the original file with the temporary file
    move /Y "!tempFile!" "!filePath!"
)

echo All files processed.
pause
```

---

**[EDIT]**

Please see below new code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "targetFolder=D:\ach_test"
echo Processing: !targetFolder!
pause
for %%F in ("%targetFolder%\*.txt") do (
    set "filePath=%%F"
    set "fileName=%%~nxF"
    echo Processing: !filePath!
    echo Processing: !fileName!
    rem Create a temporary file
    set "tempFile=!fileName!.tmp"
    rem Process each line in the file
    for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("!filePath!") do (
        set "line=%%L"
        rem Check if the line starts with 'IN'
     rem (comment this out) setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if "!line:~0,2!"=="IN" (
            rem Extract the first 15 characters
            set "prefix=!line:~0,15!"
            rem Remove special characters from the prefix and replace them with spaces
            for /F "delims=" %%A in ('echo !prefix! ^| findstr /R /N /C:"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"') do (
                set "line=%%A"
               setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
               for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%N in ("!line!") do (
                     endlocal
                    set "prefix=!prefix:~0,%%N!"
                )
            )
            set "line=!prefix!!line:~15!"
        )
   rem  (comment this out) endlocal
        rem Append the modified line to the temporary file
        echo !line! >> "!tempFile!"
    )
    rem Replace the original file with the temporary file
    move /Y "!tempFile!" "!filePath!"
)
echo All files processed.
pause
```

However, it doesn't give me the correct result

my input was -

```
IN1410806666                                                                                          2023-04-13                                                                                000000000000912.00000000000000912.00000000000000000.00               IV                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN1410807776                                                                                          2023-04-18                                                                                000000000000119.98000000000000119.98000000000000000.00               IV                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN6301%%                                                                                              2023-05-01                                                                                -00000000000727.74-00000000000727.74000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN23812*                                                                                              2023-06-07                                                                                -00000000000726.47-00000000000726.47000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN2190   #                                                                                            2023-05-01                                                                                -00000000000226.71-00000000000226.71000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN33268   C                                                                                           2023-06-09                                                                                -00000000000422.32-00000000000422.32000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN9864%                                                                                               2023-06-08                                                                                -00000000004379.27-00000000004379.27000000000000000.00               CM
```

My output is -

```
IN1410806666                                                                                          2023-04-13                                                                                000000000000912.00000000000000912.00000000000000000.00               IV                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN1410807776                                                                                          2023-04-18                                                                                000000000000119.98000000000000119.98000000000000000.00               IV                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN6301%%                                                                                              2023-05-01                                                                                -00000000000727.74-00000000000727.74000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN23812*                                                                                              2023-06-07                                                                                -00000000000726.47-00000000000726.47000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN2190   #                                                                                            2023-05-01                                                                                -00000000000226.71-00000000000226.71000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN33268   C                                                                                           2023-06-09                                                                                -00000000000422.32-00000000000422.32000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN9864%                                                                                               2023-06-08                                                                                -00000000004379.27-00000000004379.27000000000000000.00               CM
```

So it didn't replace the special characters with space

Please help.

Comment: Your second `endlocal` discards all changes to `!line!` after your second `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. As a result `!line!` will have the value it had prior to that second `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, which in this case would be `%%L`, _(its initial value)_. I would think that you should be able to simply remove both the second `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` line and the second `endlocal` line.

Comment: Hi, Compo, I commented out what you have suggested .. please read my new code

Comment: _"I have a batch script that removes special characters and replaces them with spaces for lines starting with 'AB' in multiple files only for the lines that starts with 'AB'."_ Ok.  _"However, I am not getting anything changed. The file remains the same."_ Uhu? Have you or have you not a batch script that do _that_ (the same thing that the long question title says). Sorry, but I can't review any code when the question description is _so convoluted_... Try to be much clearer if you want to receive better aid...

Comment: which part of your code (do you think) attempts the replacing? I can't find it.

Comment: I commented the code where it said (comment this out). There are only 2 lines, setlocal enabledelayedexpansion and endlocal

Comment: TBF, after fully explaining the issue in using them, I told you to 'remove' them, not prepend the with `rem (comment this out) `!

Comment: I just tried out what you have suggested, remove the 2 lines that had '(comment this out).I used only 1 line as input for test and still not working. My input was IN123@ and I am getting the same out where @ should be removed.

Comment: `set "prefix=!prefix:~0,%%N!"`: your `for` loop processes one line only, so `%%N` is always `1` (due to `findstr /N`). There is still no code to replace anything. `Findstr` will **always** return the **whole line** when it matches (plus the line number with `/N`). It can't be used to remove/replace anything.

Answer (score 1):

Mmmm... Your code is strange...

In first place, there is not any code that *replace* the characters, as Stephan said you before (*twice*!). Also, there are several unusual or badly used constructs, or an incorrect use of the `setlocal` scope.

I eliminated all such parts and *reprogramed the code* (didn't just *fixed it*), so I think it is working correctly now

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

set "targetFolder=D:\ach_test"
echo Processing: %targetFolder%

pause

set "alphaNum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

for %%F in ("*.txt") do (
    echo Processing: %%F
    echo Processing: %%~nxF

    rem Process each line in the file
    (for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%%F") do (
        set "line=%%L"

        rem Check if the line starts with 'IN'
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if "!line:~0,2!"=="IN" (

            rem Remove special characters from the first 15 characters and replace them with spaces
            for /L %%i in (0,1,14) do for %%C in ("!line:~%%i,1!") do (
                set /A oneAfter=%%i+1
                for %%j in (!oneAfter!) do  (
                   if "%%~C" equ "=" (
                       set "line=!line:~0,%%i! !line:~%%j!"
                   ) else if /I "!alphaNum:%%~C=!" equ "%alphaNum%" (
                       set "line=!line:~0,%%i! !line:~%%j!"
                   )
                )
            )

        )

        rem Append the original or modified line to the temporary file
        echo !line!
        endlocal

    )) > "%%~nF.tmp"

    rem Replace the original file with the temporary file
    move /Y "%%~nF.tmp" "%%F"
)

echo All files processed.
pause
```

There are a couple characters that may produce a faulty replacement. The equal-sign is one of them and it is processed individually in the code. If you found another problematic character, it must also needs to be processed individually.

PS - I suggest you to change the question title to a much shorter one! **`;)`**

**EDIT 27/06/2023**: *Input and output example added*

This is the input:

```
IN1410806666                                                                                          2023-04-13                                                                                000000000000912.00000000000000912.00000000000000000.00               IV                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN1410807776                                                                                          2023-04-18                                                                                000000000000119.98000000000000119.98000000000000000.00               IV                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN6301%%                                                                                              2023-05-01                                                                                -00000000000727.74-00000000000727.74000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN23812*                                                                                              2023-06-07                                                                                -00000000000726.47-00000000000726.47000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN2190   #                                                                                            2023-05-01                                                                                -00000000000226.71-00000000000226.71000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN33268   C                                                                                           2023-06-09                                                                                -00000000000422.32-00000000000422.32000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN9864%                                                                                               2023-06-08                                                                                -00000000004379.27-00000000004379.27000000000000000.00               CM
```

And this is the output:

```
IN1410806666                                                                                          2023-04-13                                                                                000000000000912.00000000000000912.00000000000000000.00               IV                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN1410807776                                                                                          2023-04-18                                                                                000000000000119.98000000000000119.98000000000000000.00               IV                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN6301                                                                                                2023-05-01                                                                                -00000000000727.74-00000000000727.74000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN23812                                                                                               2023-06-07                                                                                -00000000000726.47-00000000000726.47000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN2190                                                                                                2023-05-01                                                                                -00000000000226.71-00000000000226.71000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN33268   C                                                                                           2023-06-09                                                                                -00000000000422.32-00000000000422.32000000000000000.00               CM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
IN9864                                                                                                2023-06-08                                                                                -00000000004379.27-00000000004379.27000000000000000.00               CM
```

Comment: Hi, Aacini, Thanks very much. It's almost there for what I need. I will show you what I am looking for . e.g. my input is IN1*34             ABCDE. I need to have my output as  IN134        with a space at the end (not replacing with a space,  so the position of ABCDE remains intact. I have tried different ways but still not working. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Well, that is precisely what my program does. The special caracters `%*#` are replaced by a space each in the first 15 characters of the lines, so the date at column 103 remains at same place. I added to my answer your example input file and the output my program produce with such an input. Didn't you tested my code in the same way?

Comment: Yes, I did and use another file provided by the user. Your code  is fine but now I need to strip the special character and put the space at the end of the field and still keeping the next field (date) at column 103. I apologize  for not explaining well enough.

Comment: Please see my input and output with your code

Comment: IN8\992DF9                                                                                            2022-12-30                                                                                000000000001319.03000000000001319.03000000000000000.00               IV

Comment: IN8 992DF9                                                                                            2022-12-30                                                                                000000000001319.03000000000001319.03000000000000000.00               IV

Comment: I would like strip the space that is replacing the special character but keeping the next field intact

Comment: Please, edit the whole question so it reflects your real requirements. It's a bad practice to "patch" the question via comments... And _change the title_ to another, more concise one. After completed these changes, post a comment here as an advice...